# Running Hadoop 2.8.0 on Windows 10, YarnRuntimeException Permissions incorrectly set, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rw-rw-rw-

Tags: hadoop

I recently followed article https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Hadoop-2-8-2-on-Windows-10-for-practice, and tried to run Hadoop on my Windows 10 machine (i7, 16GB RAM). It started correctly - no issues. But when I installed Docker, which inturn enabled Hyper-V, **I started to get following failure while starting NodeManager**

```
18/12/19 21:29:31 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8040: starting
18/12/19 21:29:31 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Permissions incorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-username/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rw-rw-rw-
18/12/19 21:29:31 INFO localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Attempting to initialize /tmp/hadoop-username/nm-local-dir
18/12/19 21:29:31 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Permissions incorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-username/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rw-rw-rw-
18/12/19 21:29:31 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-username/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions incorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-username/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rw-rw-rw-
...
```

Following services start without any issues

- ResourceManager
- datanode
- namenode

Answer (score 0):

Changing yarn-site.xml to this worked for me. In my case was due to Windows Domain not reachable.

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
     <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>c:\my\hadoop-2.7.1\tmp-nm</value>
</property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
        <value>98.5</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```